# why iOS project archiving takes longer than building?

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an application. It takes 20 seconds to build into my iPhone, but couple of minutes to archive into an IPA, what is the reason of this ?

I use `Xcode 6`, and `Swift`.

EDIT :

i once read about dsym option that could be turned off, and save a lot of time, are there any other options that i can turn off to save time?

Comment: how many times do you archive the project on a regular day if that causes such a big issue for you?

Comment: you miss my point, i once read about dsym option that could be turned off, and save a lot of time, are there any other options that i can turn off to save time?

Comment: yes, but usually, we don't do archives but for certain milestones only (beta, rc, fc, final), literally you need to archive the project 5-6 time during a complete development session... so, the point is, why would you need to worry about that few minutes times? it is way far under any conscious level.

Comment: my clients require daily build, and sometimes xcode gives a bug 2 or 3 times before finishing archiving (i don't know why), so this is about 4 hours a week wasted, don't forget that i stop development in this period.

Comment: your way to manage the development session sounds terrible to me; and it also seems your client does not really trust in you. :(

Answer (score 3):

That's obvious because the archiving does a lot of optimisation and compression on the code and resources (images etc), which takes additional time than just installing a debug build.

Comment: yeah, but can i turn that optimization off to archive faster?

Comment: One of the option from Xcode is : https://imageoptim.com/xcode-no-compress.png

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it archiving an app is building it ánd compressing it's not weird that it takes longer than only building. You may have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa_(file_extension)

Comment: this question is solved, thanks.